# Calculate memory usage of (compact) strings

Tags: java, string, java-9

With java's compact strings feature, is there a public api to get the actual encoding or memory usage of a string? I could call either package private method `coder` or private method `isLatin1` and adjust the calculation, but both will result in an `Illegal reflective access` warning.

```
Method isLatin1 = String.class.getDeclaredMethod("isLatin1");
isLatin1.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println((boolean)isLatin1.invoke("Jörn"));
System.out.println((boolean)isLatin1.invoke("foobar"));
System.out.println((boolean)isLatin1.invoke("\u03b1"));
```

Comment: There is a good reason for this warning. You’re querying an implementation detail which is not guaranteed to be there or to behave as you expect. What if a future version chooses between three different optimized encodings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty easy with [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) (but I am not entirely sure this is what you want):

```
String left = "Jörn"; 
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(left).totalSize()); // 48 bytes

String right = "foobar";
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(right).totalSize()); // 48 bytes

String oneMore = "\u03b1";
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(oneMore).totalSize()); // 48 bytes
```

For encoding there isn't a public API, but you can deduce it...

```
private static String encoding(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c : arr) {
        if (c >>> 8 != 0) {
            return "UTF16";
        }
    }
    return "Latin1";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about JOL, interesting to see the overhead of small strings. I'll probably not use it directly but estimate the size based on those values.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann right. there are samples in that project that are far more interesting, like inheritance gaps, or a huge gap in `.class`, etc